# Setting opacity in IFrame

Tags: html, css

I dont seem to be able to get set the background-image of an IFrame with these 2 requirements.

- The IFrame shouldn't be transparent, while the opacity of the background-image should be `0.1`
- The background has to repeat, because there is a really long `<p>` tag

And here is the code with the problem that the background-image doesn't reapeat, any idea on how to achieve these 2 requirements :)?

```
<body style="background-color:white;font-family: arial;">

<div style=" 

  background-image: url(backgroundchat.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  opacity: 0.1;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;">

 </div>
```

The IFrame basically calls this page, but is on a different one, but for those interested:

```
<iframe id="ifrim" frameborder="0" src="/chathistory.php"></iframe>
```

Comment: where is the `iframe` in your example? could you post a more accurate example?

Comment: @MoinZaman there is nothing really special about the iframe its basically just setting the src of the file above, but added it :)

Comment: @TryingToCode "*I dont seem to be able to get set the background-image of an IFrame with these 2 requirements.*" **It's because the styles you have are on divs not the iframe which could be there maybe? HTML layout needs to include everything within the iframe's area of at least 2 levels of elements above and below it.**